# Jsoup - how to select elements within an element

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to select an element inside another element for example:

```
<video>
    <source src = "" />
</video>
```

Android code to select the source element within video video case does not have the src attribute

```
private String getVideoSrc(Document doc){
        String src = null;

        Element video = doc.select("video").first();
        Element source = null;

        if(video.attr("src") == null){
            source = video.select("source").first();
        }

        if(video.attr("src") !=null){
            src = video.attr("src");
        }else if(source.attr("src") != null){
            src = source.attr("src");
        }

        return src;
    }
```

When there is a src attribute in video it returns the content normally, if it does not exist, however exists in source that is inside video it does not even get the tag

Example:

```
Element video = doc.select("video").first();
Element source = video.select("source").first();
```

[This](http://www.animep.net/video/3881) is the page with the element that does not work, but the application that I'm building must get the src attribute of the maximum number of possible sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isEmpty()` in your if-conditions, instead of `null`.

```
String src = null;

Element video = doc.select("video").first();
Element source = null;

if(video.attr("src").isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("is null");
    source = video.select("source").first();
}

if(!video.attr("src").isEmpty()){
    src = video.attr("src");
}else if(!source.attr("src").isEmpty()){
    src = source.attr("src");
}
```